# the first qt-opencv program

Tags: qt, opencv

My error is:

> error: C2228: left of '.open' must have class/struct/union and i dont
>   know to fix that.

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\video\video.hpp>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/flann/miniflann.hpp"

using namespace cv; <i> all the new API is put into "cv" namespace. Export its content</i>
using namespace std;

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent),ui(new Ui::Dialog){
    ui->setupUi(this);
    capture.open("E:\\Six Degree of Separation.avi");
    tmrTimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(tmrTimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(ProcessFrameAndUpdateGUI()));
    tmrTimer ->start(20);
}
```

Comment: Where has `capture` come from?

Comment: capture->open("E:\\Six Degree of Separation.avi");

Comment: @Willy That's not where it was created.

Answer (score 1):

There should be an instance of `cv::VideoCapture capture;`.
You can check whether it is open with `capture.isOpened()`. It returns true if the file was open successfully or if the camera has been initialized successfully.